# Read logged in User details from SSO server in Blue mix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am working on Node.js application with Cloudant database. I was able to do IBM IDP authentication with SSO server on Blue mix via the SSO service.

My issue occurs after successful authentication, I am unable to get JSON object that can give me all the user attributes that I need, for example, is the logged in person a manager? if yes then his serial number, name etc

Does anyone know how to retrieve the information from IBM SSO service?
Kindly let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `request.user` object returned after successful authentication. It returns some information about the logged in user, but each provider returns different data.

For example, for LinkedIn logged users it returns displayName, firstName, lastName and emailAddress.

The snippet code below prints the request.user JSON object in the application log, so you can see what is available and retrieve as needed.

```
app.get('/auth/sso/callback', function(req, res, next) { 

    var redirect_url = req.session.originalUrl;                
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect: '/hello',                                
        failureRedirect: '/failure',                        
    })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/hello', ensureAuthenticated, function(request, response) {

    response.send('Hello, '+ request.user['id'] + '!\n' + '<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.user));     

});
```

After user logs in you can run:

```
cf logs <app-name> --recent
```

to see results from `console.log` code.