# How to get userDetails from SSO login page?

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on

AngularJS

Home page url is : localhost:8080/angular/home.html

```
SSO : https://sso-nprd.xyz.com/autho/forms
```

Whenever i am hitting above URL first it will redirect to SSO login screen, there i will enter username and password then it will redirect to home page

at home page i want username.

My application is purely in AngularJS. I don't know wheather its possible or not!

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: [Read logged in User details from SSO server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33514077/3543808)

Comment: @GangadharJannu Could you please tell how to take the details from SSO server in JS/AngularJS.